# Как отфильтровать объект по убыванию

Tags: javascript, циклы, сортировка, объекты, фильтр

```
{
    "15245": {
        "11": 0,
        "12": 2,
        "13": 3,
        "14": 3,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 1,
        "18": 0,
        "19": 4,
        "20": 2,
        "21": 4,
        "22": 1,
        "23": 0
    },
    "15246": {
        "11": 0,
        "12": 2,
        "13": 0,
        "14": 3,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
        "18": 0,
        "19": 4,
        "20": 2,
        "21": 1,
        "22": 3,
        "23": 3
    },
    "15247": {
        "11": 0,
        "12": 3,
        "13": 2,
        "14": 3,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
        "18": 0,
        "19": 2,
        "20": 4,
        "21": 4,
        "22": 2,
        "23": 2
    },
    "15248": {
        "11": 0,
        "12": 1,
        "13": 3,
        "14": 4,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 3,
        "18": 1,
        "19": 4,
        "20": 2,
        "21": 3,
        "22": 2,
        "23": 3
    },
    "15249": {
        "11": 0,
        "12": 1,
        "13": 0,
        "14": 1,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
        "18": 0,
        "19": 1,
        "20": 3,
        "21": 0,
        "22": 3,
        "23": 2
    },
    "15250": {
        "11": 0,
        "12": 3,
        "13": 4,
        "14": 3,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
        "18": 2,
        "19": 5,
        "20": 4,
        "21": 5,
        "22": 3,
        "23": 3
    },
    "15251": {
        "11": 0,
        "12": 0,
        "13": 0,
        "14": 2,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 1,
        "18": 0,
        "19": 5,
        "20": 1,
        "21": 2,
        "22": 1,
        "23": 2
    },
    "15252": {
        "11": 0,
        "12": 1,
        "13": 0,
        "14": 4,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
        "18": 0,
        "19": 4,
        "20": 1,
        "21": 0,
        "22": 3,
        "23": 2
    },
    "15253": {
        "11": 0,
        "12": 3,
        "13": 2,
        "14": 3,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
        "18": 1,
        "19": 3,
        "20": 4,
        "21": 4,
        "22": 2,
        "23": 2
    }
}
```

Например:

```
15245 - товар
11 - пункт выдачи
12 - пункт выдачи
13 - пункт выдачи
```

Значения пункта выдачи это остаток товара на пункте выдачи.

```
 "11": 0, магазин - количество товара
 "12": 3, магазин - количество товара
 "13": 2, магазин - количество товара
 "14": 3, магазин - количество товара
 "15": 0, магазин - количество товара
 "16": 0, магазин - количество товара
 "17": 0, магазин - количество товара
 "18": 1, магазин - количество товара
 "19": 3, магазин - количество товара
 "20": 4, магазин - количество товара
 "21": 4, магазин - количество товара
 "22": 2, магазин - количество товара
 "23": 2  магазин - количество товара
```

Что должно получится в итоге:

```
{
    "15245": {
        "19": 4,
        "21": 4,
        "13": 3,
        "14": 3,
        "20": 2,
        "22": 1,
        "17": 1,
        "16": 0,
        "18": 0,
        "23": 0
    },
    "15246": {
        "19": 4,
        "14": 3,
        "22": 3,
        "23": 3,
        "12": 2,
        "20": 2,
        "21": 1,
        "11": 0,
        "13": 0,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
        "18": 0
    },
    "15247": {
        "20": 4,
        "21": 4,
        "12": 3,
        "14": 3,
        "13": 2,
        "19": 2,
        "22": 2,
        "23": 2,
        "11": 0,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
        "18": 0

    },
    "15248": {
        "14": 4,
        "19": 4,
        "13": 3,
        "17": 3,
        "21": 3,
        "23": 3,
        "20": 2,
        "22": 2,
        "12": 1,
        "18": 1,
        "11": 0,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0
    },
    "15249": {
        "20": 3,
        "22": 3,
        "23": 2,
        "12": 1,
        "14": 1,
        "19": 1,
        "11": 0,
        "13": 0,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
        "18": 0,
        "21": 0

    },
    "15250": {
        "19": 5,
        "21": 5,
        "13": 4,
        "20": 4,
        "12": 3,
        "14": 3,
        "22": 3,
        "23": 3,
        "18": 2,
        "11": 0,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
    },
    "15251": {
        "19": 5,
        "14": 2,
        "21": 2,
        "23": 2,
        "17": 1,
        "20": 1,
        "22": 1,
        "12": 0,
        "13": 0,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "18": 0
    },
    "15252": {
        "14": 4,
        "19": 4,
        "22": 3,
        "23": 2,
        "12": 1,
        "20": 1,
        "11": 0,
        "13": 0,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
        "18": 0,
        "21": 0,
    },
    "15253": {
        "20": 4,
        "21": 4,
        "12": 3,
        "14": 3,
        "19": 3,
        "13": 2,
        "22": 2,
        "23": 2,
        "18": 1,
        "11": 0,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
    }
}
```

Как мне отcортировать объект с товаром так, чтобы количество по точкам шло по убыванию на JS?

Comment: Объект впринципе не сортируется(вы же имели ввиду сортировку, а не фильтрацию?). Что такое " остаток вкуса товара"?

Comment: Да, "фильтровать по убыванию" тоже красиво

Comment: а вы можете написать пример того массива/объекта, который хотите получить? из своих данных

Comment: С какой целью(для чего) вы хотите поменять расположение ключей в объекте местами? Браузер, например, сам отсортирует все ключи по возрастанию(по названию ключей, а не по значению), так что это немнгого бессмысленное занятие

Comment: @SwaD, спасибо за интерес! Сортировка нужна для распределения по наличию, то есть точка где больше всего товара была сверху, где меньше всего снизу.

Comment: @nörbörnën, отредактировал и приложил отсортированный объект.

Comment: С ключами в виде чисел - это не получится. Нужно формировать массив объектов, e которых будет например id:XXX, count:YYY.

Comment: в js "порядок" ключей объекта не гарантирован и зависит от среды выполнения (кое-где гарантирован) https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8. так что лучше бросьте эту затею и используйте Map или массивы (см комментарий Шиманского)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, почему то, так и думал, но решил удостоверится здесь. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @nörbörnën, спасибо за ответ, приму к сведению!